# in this code if coonditiion is failed then it should return the statment after if block but iam getting blank page can anyone help me

Tags: reactjs

```
const use={firstName : 'vineeth',lastName : 'Reddy'};   
function display(use)
{   
    return use.firstName+"  "+use.lastName;  
}  
function welcome(user)
{  
    if(user)
    {  
       return <p>welcome {display(user)}</p>;
    }
    return    <h1>welcome stranger{display(use)}</h1>;
}
ReactDOM.render(welcome(user),document.getElementById('root'));
```

Comment: Please can you [edit] your question so that the title contains a summary and the question itself is in the body?

Comment: `<h1>welcome stranger{display(use)}</h1>;` you want to pass `user` not `use` to `display`

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo in the code, change `use` to `user`  on the object declaration:

```
const user = { firstName: 'vineeth', lastName: 'Reddy' };
```

---

While interpreting your code, I want to point what I guess you are trying to achieve

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

const user = { firstName: 'vineeth', lastName: 'Reddy' };

function display(user) {
    return user.firstName + ' ' + user.lastName;
}

function welcome(user) {
    if (user) {
        return <p>welcome {display(user)}</p>;
    }
    // in case you don't get an user object in the args, probably you want to use a default user to say hello
    // const stranger = { firstName: 'name?', lastName: 'lastname?' };
    // return <h1>welcome stranger {display(stranger)}</h1>;

    // but I think would be clearer just: greetings mr. stranger
    return <h1>welcome stranger</h1>;
}

ReactDOM.render(welcome(user), document.getElementById('root1')); // -> welcome vineeth Reddy
ReactDOM.render(welcome(null), document.getElementById('root2')); // -> welcome stranger
```

Please, let me know if I am wrong